# Maximum RabbitMQ Prefetch count

Tags: java, rabbitmq, prefetch, rabbitmq-exchange, qos

RabbitMQ 3.8.7 Erlang 23.0.2

I am using a Java client in order to configure my RabbitMQ queue.

While trying to set up the Prefetch count using `channel.basicQos` API to 132,000, it seems in the "consumers" section in the RabbitMQ GUI it is always set to 65,535.

Is it possible that this is the maximum value of the Prefetch count? it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.java "Note the prefetch count must be between 0 and 65535 (unsigned short in AMQP 0-9-1)."